# SQL IF LESS THAN AND GREATER THAN in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, case, iif

I would like to use CASE WHEN THEN in WHERE or agregat function IIF or something else that would work like this:

```
@iKapacitet
AS
SELECT ID, Name
FROM Private-Accommodation
WHERE [Private-Accommodation].[Otok]='Rab'AND 
IIF(@iKapacitet = 1,[Private-Accommodation].[maxPersons] < 3,
IIF(@iKapacitet = 2, [Private-Accommodation].[maxPersons] < 3 AND [Private-Accommodation].[maxPersons] > 5, 
[Private-Accommodation].[maxPersons] BETWEEN 4 AND 6))
ORDER BY [Private-Accommodation].[RedniBr]
```

If it is easier with CASE:

```
CASE @iKapacitet 
WHEN 1 THEN (CASE [Private-Accommodation].[maxBrOsoba] WHEN < 3)
WHEN 2 THEN (CASE [Private-Accommodation].[maxBrOsoba] WHEN < 3 AND > 5)
WHEN 3 THEN (CASE [Private-Accommodation].[maxPersons] BETWEEN 4 AND 6)
END
```

Comment: pls state ur question clearly so that others can help u

Answer (score 2):

It is usually clearer to leave if/case logic outside of `where` clauses.  You might consider:

```
WHERE [Private-Accommodation].[Otok] = 'Rab' AND 
      ((@iKapacitet = 1 AND [Private-Accommodation].[maxPersons] < 3) OR
       (@iKapacitet = 2 AND [Private-Accommodation].[maxPersons] < 3) AND [Private-Accommodation].[maxPersons] > 5) OR
       (@iKapacitet NOT IN (1, 2) AND [Private-Accommodation].[maxPersons] BETWEEN 4 AND 6)
      )
```